# Weblogic new deployment reverting to old code

Tags: deployment, weblogic, war

I am currently trying to deploy code from .WAR file using a Weblogic Console.  Currently it reverts to the Deployment that I had already deleted.  No matter what changes I make it still reverts to the old code.  What can I do to deploy my new code.

Answer (score 1):

- Stop your managed server (if that's where it's deployed)
- Stop the old deployment
- Delete the old deployment
- Activate changes
- Install the new war file
- Activate changes

If the above doesn't work, it is possible there is some caching going on. If that's the case try the following:

Uninstall your deployment as above. Go to the `/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/` directory and delete:

- tmp
- cache
- logs
- data

Then restart your server and deploy your new .war file.