# How to resolve exception "weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '' is already in use by the module: / application"?

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I have gone through the Question:
[[weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '' is already in use by the module: / application:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033609/weblogic-application-moduleexception-context-path-is-already-in-use-by-the-m][1])
and followed as answer of the question says; but still getting the same exception:

```
**> Deployment failed. The message was:
```

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path
>   '/socketss-war' is already in use by the module:
>   /Socketss-war application: Socketss
>   D:\NetBeansProjects\Socketss\Socketss-war\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1056:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.**

Any guidance or suggestion would be highly appreciable.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using autodeploy like that link mentioned? If you're not - you need to open the weblogic admin console and removed your old deployment. See some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049332/weblogic-new-deployment-reverting-to-old-code/22052585#22052585

Comment: Yes I deleted all the previous Deployments and 
now it's running fine; but I guess its not a solution because what if I want to run two programs concurrently.

Comment: You can't have them with the exact same name OR you can create 2 managed servers and run one program on each. There are many options there but naming them differently is probably the easiest

Comment: Yes obviously sir; 
but actually I did not give the same name to two or more programs; and that is why  I don't know what went wrong and the exception...;
May be I made some mistake..
Thank u so much JAZAKALLAH Khair! 
Response was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleException` come due to improper Build.
Go through step by step.

- Update project
- Restart your eclipse
- Remove project from server
- clean server and redeploy your project

Now publish it, I hope now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Try to deploy from Netbeans.

The Weblogic eclipse plugin is, in my experience, the worst deployment plugin I've ever seen. If you are using a patched weblogic - such as 12.1.2 with Patch Set Update 6 - your deployment from eclipse might miraculously not work with such an error.

If you are able to deploy the WAR file without IDE by going to the deploy view, I recommend that you try using Netbeans to deploy and see how it goes.

Notice as well that the outcome of trying to deploy from eclipse as exploded war or as virtual application is not the same. Typically both do not work with different exceptions, depending on the patches you are using.

In my case, I have two local installations of weblogic 12.1.2. One with the patch set update and another one without. From eclipse, It is only possible to deploy to the one without. From Netbeans, deployment works regardless of the instance.